# How to check if the sequence of ints has even and odd numbers alternating using LINQ, C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, extension-methods

Let's say I have a list of ints in c# like this:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 7, 20, 3 };
```

Is there a way of checking that it has *alternating* **odd** and **even** numbers in it (like in the example above: if *one* if them is *even* then the *next* must be *odd* or vice versa)?

I know it's simple to check it in a loop, but I'm trying to implement this using **LINQ** and extension methods only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyze the problem. What does it mean alternating parity?

```
  index : value : value + index
  ------------------------------
      0 :     1 : 1 - note, all sums are odd
      1 :     2 : 3
      2 :     7 : 9
         ....
```

Or

```
  index : value : value + index
  ------------------------------
      0 :     2 : 2 - note, all sums are even
      1 :     1 : 2
      2 :     6 : 8
         ....
```

As you can see (and you can easily prove it) alternating parity means that
`index + value` sums are either *all* `odd` or *all* `even`. Let's check it with a help of Linq:

```
  List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 7, 20, 3, 79 };

  bool result = numbers
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Select((item, index) => Math.Abs((long)item + (long)index))
    .Aggregate((s, a) => s % 2 == a % 2 ? s % 2 : -1) >= 0;
```

Notes to the implementation:

1. `DefaultIfEmpty()` - empty sequence has all (all zero) values alternating; however, `Aggregate` has nothing to aggregate and throws exception. Let's turn empty sequence into one element sequence.
2. `(long)` in order to prevent *integer overflow* (`int.MaxValue + index` can well be out of `int` range)
3. `Math.Abs`: c# can return *negative remainder* (e.g. `-1 % 2`); we don't want an additional check for this, so let's work with absolute values
4. However, we can exploit this effect (`-1 % 2 == -1`) in the final `Aggregate`

Extension Method solution I hope is easier to understand:

```
  public static bool IsAlternating(this IEnumerable<int> source) {
    if (null == source)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    bool expectedZero = false;
    bool first = true;

    foreach (int item in source) {
      int actual = item % 2;

      if (first) {
        first = false;
        expectedZero = actual == 0;
      } 
      else if (actual == 0 && !expectedZero || actual != 0 && expectedZero) 
        return false;  

      expectedZero = !expectedZero;
    } 

    return true;
  }
```

Note, that the loop solution (extension method) is *more efficient*: it returns `false` *immediately* when pattern doesn't meet.

Comment: Elegant solution, although it's worth noting that the suggestion using standard LINQ methods will iterate through the whole collection before giving an answer even if the first two items break the alternating rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with LINQ in this way. you can check if there is atelast one even item at add place or an odd item at even place.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 7, 20, 3 };
var temp = numbers.Where((x, i) => (i % 2 == 0 && x % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 == 1 && x % 2 == 1)).Take(1);
int count = temp.Count();
if(count == 0)
{
    //true
}
else
{
    //false
}
```

**Note**: Assuming that you are expecting even numbers at even place and odd numbers at an odd place.

Comment: Possible counter example: `new List<int>() { 8, 1, 2, 7};`, expected `true` (odd and even numbers are *alternating*), actual `false`. Please, note that now even numbers are at even places, when odd numbers are on odd places

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I have added the assumption in the answer. Thank you for your notice

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Aggregate` to determine if a sequence is alternating.

Let's assume that if there's 0 or 1 elements then the result is true.
You can modify this logic however you see fit.

Based on this an extension method can be created:

```
    public static bool IsAlternatingParitySequenceVerbose(this IEnumerable<int> col)
    {
        // state:
        // -1 - sequence is not alternating
        //  0 - even
        //  1 - odd

        if (!col.Any())
            return true;

        //check if first value is even
        var firstState = Math.Abs(col.First() % 2);

        var IsAlternating = col.Skip(1).Aggregate(firstState, (state, val) =>
        {
            if (state == -1)
                return -1;

            var current = Math.Abs(val % 2);
            if (current == state)
                return -1;

            return current;
        });

        return IsAlternating != -1;
    }
```

And then make a one-liner out of it:

```
    public static bool IsAlternatingParitySequence(this IEnumerable<int> col) =>
        !col.Any()
        || col.Skip(1).Aggregate(Math.Abs(col.First() % 2), (state, val) =>
                state == -1
                    ? -1
                    : Math.Abs(val % 2) is var current && current == state
                    ? -1
                    : current
            ) != -1;
```